# Hide the JSON file from website's users and call it in the Android app

Tags: json, web, host

I want to write a program that receives information from my website using JSON.
The JSON's file for example is located at the following address on host.
http://example.com/jfile.json

In the program that I've written on Android, I call this file and then do the operations that I want to apply to the data correctly.

But the point here is that I do not want my user's website access to the JSON file by typing  (http://example.com/jfile.json) and I want only my application to access this file.

Is it possible? if yes, How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a header to your site to get the access token:

```
Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: Basic "accestoken"
```

and then add it to your app:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
   HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
   headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
   headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer AccesToken");
   return headers;
  }
```

https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-token